# How to create table with dynamic amount of columns

Tags: data-binding, tableview, javafx-2

Thare is a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) at javaFX documentation page. This example describes how to make tableView, if you have some sertain java class, which can tell you which columns you are going to have. (That is a Person class in this example).

But what if i do not have any specific class, and number of columns can vary from time to time?
In my case i have such data structure:

```
class TableData{ 
    List<Row> rows; //A list with all my rows i need to have in my table
}

class Row{
    List<Column> columns; //Cells\Columns for every row. 
}

class Column{
    Attribute attr; //Each column - is somethig like a wrapper for the real data i need to show in a cell;
}

class Attribute{ //My precues data
    String name;
    SupportingInfo info;
}

class SupportingInfo{//Some supporting fields...
    String name;
    String value;
    //...etc....
}
```

So, my case is very similar to [this one](http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/19/dyanmic-tableview-data-from-database/).
The only differents is that data from the case above is not binded with its representation in javaFX table (so, even if some one will make extra controls to edit this data in a tableView, the actual object with that data will never know about it.), because it(data) goes to the table like some strings, not like some objects;

So, what do i need - is to push data to the table (like that: **table.setItems(tableData)**), set some set Factories, to give user ability to edit data, and to have this edited data in my tableData object;

Here are some code ive tried to make for this purpose:

```
//prepare my table
private void createTableHeader(TableView table, List<Attribute> ias) {
    int i = 0;
    for (final Attribute ia : ias) {
        final int j = i;
        i++;
        TableColumn tc = new TableColumn(ia.getName());
        tc.setSortable(true);
        tc.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<List<Attribute>, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<List<Attribute>, String> arg0) {
                if(arg0.getValue().get(j).getSupportingInfo() == null){
                    arg0.getValue().get(j).setSupportingInfo(new SupportingInfo());
                }
                return new SimpleObjectProperty(arg0.getValue().get(j),"value");
            }
        });
        table.getColumns().add(tc);
    }
}

//loading some data to my tableView
private void createTableBody(TableView curTable, List<Row> rows) {  
    ObservableList<List<Attribute>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (Row row : rows) {
        data.add(row.getColumns());
    }
    curTable.setItems(data);
}   

//this one is to define some extra controls for editing data in a table by users
private void makeCellFactory(TableColumn curTableCol, final Attribute templateIa, final Document doc) {
    curTableCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
        public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
            final EditingCell cell = new EditingCell(templateIa, doc);
            return cell;
        }
    });
}
```

But, as a result, i have just empty rows in my table, with an ability to click some cell and recieve table editing controls. But there is not defult values in by table;
What am i doing wrong in my code?

Comment: I tried to put your code into a class and get it compiling but without success.  Row#getColumns should return a List of Column right but in #createTableBody it is added to a ObservableList<List<Attribute>>.  Maybe using a 2D array of Attribute would simplify things?

Comment: The table columns in the createTableHeader method are being passed as makeCellFactory  arguments? If so it's natural to expect only the last behaviour intended since I believe a TableColumn can have only one cellFactory. If you set it twice, the last one will be the valid one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i've found a solution:
ts.setCellFactory should look like this:

```
tc.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<List<Attribute>, SupportingInfo>, ObservableValue<Attribute>>() {
 @Override
 public ObservableValue<Attribute> call(CellDataFeatures<List<Attribute>, SupportingInfo> arg0) {
  return new SimpleObjectProperty(arg0.getValue().get(j),"value",arg0.getValue().get(j));
 }
});
```

Also, this code is needed to catch new values and put the incoming data to the table:

```
tc.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<List<Attribute>, Attribute>>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(CellEditEvent<List<Attribute>, Attribute> t) { t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()).get(j).setSupportingInfo(t.getNewValue().getSupportingInfo());
    }
});
```